# create object programmatically in angular 2

Tags: angular, object, typescript

I wish to create object and add data dynamically by typescript.

for Example:

```
let data={
    "date":"27-5-2017",
    "name":"John"
};
```

This is my initial object. Now I want to add some more data in it like subject.

```
"Subject1":"20"
"Subject2":"30"
```

This subject vary by student. How can I add this Subject into data object.

Comment: Down Votters can you define your whats wrong with this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define it as :

```
let data:any;
```

If you have already json object initialized :
Then you can use directly

```
data['dynamic_key'] = value;
```

If not initialized and want to add for the first time

```
data = {'dynamic_key' : value };
```

Answer (score 3):

I would create a class for this. The benefits to this are ensuring the property names are constant compared to when you dynamically / manually add a property through methods such as `data['subject1'] = 'math';` or `data.subject1 = math`.

```
class Student{

  public name: string;
  public dateOfEntry: string;
  public subjects: Array<Subject>;

  constructor(name: string, dateOfEntry: string){
    this.name = name;
    this.dateOfEntry = dateOfEntry;

    this.subjects = new Array<Subject>();
  }

  public addSubject(subject: Subject){
    // if we have not already added this subject to the list
    if(!this.subjects.find(val => val == subject))
      this.subjects.push(subject);
  }

}


class Subject{
    public name: string;

    constructor(name: string){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then when you want to craete a new student...

```
let bob: Student = new Student("bob", new Date().toString());
bob.addSubject(new Subject("Math")); // adds to list
bob.addSubject(new Subject("English")); // adds to list
bob.addSubject(new Subject("Math")); // WILL NOT ADD - already exists
```

Comment: Thank you. This is great idea to make class of it. I will surely look into this as well. Currently I found an answer

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot I would strongly recommend this over the selected answer - but glad you found a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can directly assign like this.

```
data.Subject1 = "20"
data.Subject2 = "30"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do `data.key = value`.

Comment: prototype is undefined.

Comment: hmm, checked at my end. Prototype doesnt work with TS. updated the answer.